# Adjusting Canvas size to image size with Pixi.js

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, javascript-objects, pixi.js

I'm working on a really basic image editor (designed primarily to place text on an image), using PixiJS... though this may be more of a Canvas question, I'm not sure how to classify it as I'm green to Canvas and completely new to Pixi. Unfortunately I can't replicate the behavior in JSFiddle. As of now, I only have this running on localhost, but if anyone has suggestions on how to share this code, I'm open for any feedback.

The idea is that users would be able to select a image to edit (templates for various forms of signage), with the canvas rendering to the size of the image and adding said image as a child on loading the page. For now I'm using a 400 x 650px placeholder for testing purposes. The problem is that on an initial loading or hard refresh of the page, the canvas size defaults to Pixi's 800 x 600px. Soft refreshing the page will size the canvas to the image's dimensions, but I'd like to fix this issue... and I'm sure it's probably an easy fix, but I'm in uncharted waters here. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

I apologize if some of this code looks wonky, I'm fully aware this is a huge mess right now.

**Javascript** (this is actually in an AngularJS controller for the time being)

```
var img = new Image();
var signagetemplate = "placeholderSIGN.png";
img.src = signagetemplate;

var canwidth = img.width;
var canheight = img.height;

var renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(canwidth, canheight, {
    transparent: true,
    resolution: 1
});
document.getElementById('display').appendChild(renderer.view);

var stage = new PIXI.Container();

PIXI.loader
.add("signitem", signagetemplate)
.load(setup);

function setup() {
    signitem = new PIXI.Sprite(
    PIXI.loader.resources["signitem"].texture
    );

    stage.addChild(signitem);
    renderer.render(stage);
}
```

**Edit 9/21/17**
I've tried using Pixi's built-in loader as suggested by Hachi in the comments to load the image, but it doesn't seem to load it at all. In the log, it's undefined. I don't understand this loader...

```
loader.add('signitem', signagetemplate);
loader.load((loader, resources) => {
    console.log(resources.name, 'loaded.', 'progress:',resources.progressChunk, '%');
});
loader.load(setup);
```

Comment: After some extra debugging, I realized that it's something to do with loading the image. `canwidth` and `canheight` return values of 0 until it's re-loaded. I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: note that ` img.src` is a setter and causes the image to load. make sure to wait until is loaded, using the `load` event handler, to use the actual image data, not the defaults.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have time to replicate the code now and verify, but also taking into account the comments above, I think you are just not waiting for the image to load. Use the loader like in pixi docs: http://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.loaders.Loader.html , now you make an image out of it and push it to the image, I'm not sure that works. Then AFTER the image has loaded (in setup-function) get the width and height there, when the browser really knows the dimensions.

Comment: Well I tried grabbing the dimensions in the load function (see updated code), but I'm still getting the PIXI default dimensions. I still don't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Nevermind, updated code was causing more problems. Re-edited.

Comment: I attempted using the built-in loader, but I can't seem to get it to work. I feel more lost than I was before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. All of the examples I found for working with the loader confused me a little bit, mainly just the syntax for entering basic JavaScript. Whether or not this is the cleanest way of going about the problem, I'm not sure, but this seems to work, at least locally. My feelings will not be hurt if someone comes along with a better solution.

```
var container = new PIXI.Container();
var signagetemplate = //Image to be loaded
var loader = PIXI.loader;
var canwidth;
var canheight;
var renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer({
    transparent: true,
    resolution: 1
});

loader.add("signtemp", signagetemplate)
loader.on('complete', function(loader, resources, IMAGE) {
    var signitem = new PIXI.Sprite(loader.resources.signtemp.texture);
    canwidth = signitem.width;
    canheight = signitem.height;
    container.addChild(signitem);
})
loader.load(setup);

function setup() {
    renderer.resize(canwidth, canheight);
    renderer.render(container);     
}

document.getElementById('display').appendChild(renderer.view);
```